# WSO2 API Manager Two Parameters in Body

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I work with API Manager version 3.0.0.

In Publisher page in Resources,I need add two or more parameters when the type is BODY with the method HTTP is POST, similar to [image: Example with Query parameter] but only permits one when parameter is Body.

Is possible to add more than one parameter BODY? and how?

Edit:

Is possible have two parameters in BODY, whit this form in API Publisher-> API Definition -> Edit, edit the service that you need similar to:

```
/v1/nipCliente: 
      post: 
        requestBody: 
          content: 
            application/x-www-form-urlencoded: 
              schema: 
                type: "object"
                properties: 
                  id_usuario: 
                    type: "string"
                  password: 
                    type: "string"
                  nip: 
                    type: "string"
          required: false
        responses: 
          200: 
            description: "ok"
        security: 
          - 
            default: []
        x-auth-type: "None"
        x-throttling-tier: "Unlimited"
```

In the same page looks that:

[image: Example]

In API Developer->Try Out, looks similar to:
[image: BODY PARAMETERS]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple body parameters in POST, PUT requests are **NOT** allowed by design because there can be only one payload for the request. [1]

If the request body contains multiple parameters, you can send it as a single json object.

The backend service method should be modified to accept the specific object model.

Ex: Say I want to send the following as the body.

```
{
   "name" : "Joe",
   "age" : 23,
   "grade" : 9
}
```

The backend service method which expects Student object.

```
@POST
public Response studentPost(Student student) {

}
```

Student Object

```
public class Student{
   String name;
   int age;
   int grade;

   ... getters/ setters ...

}
```

Or, you can use different parameters. i.e, query params + body + header params.

[1] https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#parameter-object